# Compute the nullity of linear transformation $T$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the exercise:

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real functions continuous on $\left[ a, b \right]$. If $f\,\in V$, $g=T(f)$ means that

$$ g(x) = \int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt\quad \text{for a $\le x \le b$}$$

TO determine whether $T$ is linear or not. If $T$ is linear, describe its null space and compute the nullity.

I have solved the first part of to determine the linearity of $T$:

Let $g_1 = T(f_1)$ and $g_2 = T(f_2) $ . According to the definition of transformation we can get $g_1(x) = \int_a^b\,f_1(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt$ and  $g_2(x) = \int_a^b\,f_2(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt$. Then can get
$$ \begin{align} T(f_1 + f_2) & = \int_a^b\,(f_1(t)+f_2(t))\,sin(x-t)\,dt \\
        & = \int_a^b\,f_1(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt + \int_a^b\,f_1(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt \\
        & = g_1(x) + g_2(x) \\
        & = T(f_1)+T(f_2) \end{align}
$$
And
$$ \begin{align} T(kf) & = \int_a^b\,(kf)\,sin(x-t)\,dt \\
        & = k\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt \\
        & = kT(f) \\
        \end{align}
$$
which proves that transformation $T$ is linear.

When to find out the null space we let $T(x)=0$ which means
$$
\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt=0\quad  \text{for a $\le x \le b$}
$$
I can see the trivial case of $f(x)=0$ which can be an element of null space, but failed to find out others and the basis. Is there exists any other functions in $V$ be an element, I don't know.

Any hints will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out and the proof is as follows:

$$
g(x) = \int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt\quad \text{for a $\le x \le b$}
$$
Let $g(x)=0$ it leads to
$$ \int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt=0\, \text{for a $\le x \le b$} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
 $$
And also,
$$
\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sin(x-t)\,dt  = \int_a^b\,f(t)\,(sinx\,cost - cosx\,sint)\,dt \\
  = \int_a^b\,f(t)\,sinx\,cost \,dt - \int_a^b\,f(t)\,cosx\,sint \,dt \\
=sinx\,\int_a^b\,f(t)\,cost \,dt - cosx\,\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sint \,dt
$$
Using $\eqref{eq1}$ we can get
$$
g(x)=sinx\,\int_a^b\,f(t)\,cost \,dt - cosx\,\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sint \,dt\\
=c_1 sin(x)-c_2cos(x)  \tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
where
$$
c_1=\int_a^b\,f(t)\,cost \,dt \\
c_2=\int_a^b\,f(t)\,sint \,dt
$$
Differentiate $g(x)$ we have
$$
g'(x)=c_1\,cosx + c_2\,sinx \tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
Differentiate $g'(x)$ we have
$$
g''(x)=-c_1\,sinx + c_2\,cosx \tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$

Sum equation $\eqref{eq2}$ and $\eqref{eq4}$ we have
$$
g''(x) + g(x) = 0
$$
Solve the differential equation we have $Dim(g(x)) = 2$ which means $Dim(T(V))=2$
Since V is an infinite dimensional linear space, one of $T(V)$ or $N(T)$ must be infinite-dimensional, we can get N(T) must be infinite-dimensional.
So,
$$
 N(T)\quad\text{infinite dimensional}\\
 T(V)\quad \text{with dimension}\quad2
$$